# vim tags - symbolic link

Tags: vim, ctags

I have a project as follows:

```
/dir 
   dir1
   dir2 -> symbolic-link to /otherdir
       file1
   tags *
```

- I want vim to use *THIS* tags file which includes tags for files in dir1 and dir2.
  When I edit file1, VIM cannot find the correct tags file.

I have the following setup in .vimrc:

```
set tags=tags;/
```

Is there a way to keep this file structure without explicitly telling VIM the absolute path to *tags*?

Answer (score 3):

You can append to the same ctags other tags, so for example if you want to ctag everything inside dir1 you would execute:

```
ctags -R *
```

and if you want to add some other tags from dir two:

```
ctags -R -a ~/path/to/dir2/*
```

-a is for appending.

Now what I do to always have my ctags no matter where I open my vim, is to add this line in my `.vimrc`:

```
set tags+=./tags;$HOME
```

this will look for tags in the current directory and will go down recursively to your home folder, if you would like it to search until the root folder or less just change `$HOME` for `/` or `/path/to/root/project/`

Answer (score 1):

With this line in my `~/.vimrc` and a similar layout as yours, `tags` related features (`:ts`, `<C-]>`, etc.) use the same `tags` file situated at the root of `dir`, alongside `dir1` and `dir2`.

```
set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME
```

The `tags` file is first searched in the current file's directory, then in the `cwd`, then upwards until it reaches `$HOME`.

What does `:echo tagfiles()` say when you are editing `file1`? Here it says `['/home/romainl/Desktop/dir0/tags']`.

***EDIT***

Throwing a symlink doesn't seem to change anything.

***ENDEDIT***

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a question of being in the right directory. When you start working in this project, use `:cd /dir` to get into the directory with the tags file, and make sure the `autochdir` option is turned off. Then when you edit a file inside dir2, the working directory will still be dir, and it will still find the same tags file.

If, on the other end, you end up with dir/dir2 as your working directory, that will actually mean you're in /otherdir, so when Vim looks for the tags file from there, it can't find it in that directory or in / . I suspect that's what's happening to you now.

You can see what directory you're in at any time with the `:pwd` command, just like in the shell.